# Действия в одном Активити

Tags: android

Два макета ниже и они должны представлять одно активити... при нажатии "Туда и обратно" или "В одну сторону" они должны менятся. Как это сделать на одном Активити... С двумя смогу а в одном, трудновато!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ViewPager же, нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это делается с помощью фрагментов
А вообще, тут бы ViewPager использовать, как мне кажется.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую!

Comment: Не знаю, но почему-то не могу найти View Pager в списке компонентов! Не подскажете?

Comment: Он видимо про это говорил, а view pager за слайдинг отвечает. http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/tabhost-tabwidget.php

Comment: @Omuradil, http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/228-urok-125-viewpager.html

Answer (score 1):

Делайте на активити этот заголовок и контейнер для фрагметов. По нажатиям на любую из надписей в контейнер подсовывается нужный фрагмент.